# modifying multiple Pandas columns with .map()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to modify a few columns that all the yesses and nos become 1 and 0:

```
df['Outbreak Associated', 'FSA'] = df['Outbreak Associated', 'FSA'].map({'yes': '1', 'no': '0'})
```

Doing them one at a time works, but two or more is giving me an error. I imagine there's something simple I'm missing but I can't think of what it is.

```
KeyError: ('Outbreak Associated', 'FSA')
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace`, BUT if no match get original value, not `NaN` like `map`:

```
cols = ['Outbreak Associated', 'FSA']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({'yes': '1', 'no': '0'})
```

Solutions for [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) - you can loop each column by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda funcion:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.map({'yes': '1', 'no': '0'}))
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and
[`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df[cols] = df[cols].stack().map({'yes': '1', 'no': '0'}).unstack()
```

Or using `map` for each column separately ;):

```
d = {'yes': '1', 'no': '0'}
df['Outbreak Associated'] = df['Outbreak Associated'].map(d)
df['FSA'] = df['FSA'].map(d)
```